# Generating and visualising a decision tree

Tags: java, jsp, visualization, decision-tree

I wonder if anyone is able to help or advise with the following; I have to be able to take data from a data source and to be able to visualise that data as a decision trees on a web page all. This will be a single process which is seamless to an end user.

This will be done using JSPs and Java servlets but what concerns me are the underlying products. I'm thinking of passing the data to a Weka classifier and then doing something with the .dot file it creates, i.e. maybe feeding it to GraphViz or trying to use the Google Visualization API to present an interactive display.

But, can anyone tell me if this is a viable approach or suggest alternatives?

Thanks

Martin O'Shea.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of success creating data flow graphs with graphviz (I uploaded them with a script to a MoinMoin wiki and used the graphviz plugin). That plugin even allowed to have links in the graphs, so we could keep the individual graphs small.

Answer (score 1):

For the UI we have added the JS stuff from http://www.mxgraph.com/ to display larger graphs to the user.

Your approach is viable however. GraphViz is a good tool.

Comment: I like GraphViz but its outputs are static; ideally I would prefer to have something where a user can collapse / expand nodes and click on a box to display the data at that node etc. I will look at MaxGraph though.

Comment: It looks good. But can you pre-construct the tree without the user changing it later?

Comment: yes you have full control over the tree - i suggest download and check out the examples